# Running a script from gitlab in Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins

I have an sql script in Github that I would like to run in my Jenkins build. I connected to GitHub in SCM through ssh keys and have connected to the database in the build step (using execute shell). Now, I would like to run that sql script on the database I connected to. I'm not sure how to call it from GitHub and select the specific version I would like to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `sqlplus` setup in the Jenkins server. First, check out the script from Github and then you can directly pass the `.sql` script to `sqlplus`. See the below example. You can simply use the `@` and the script location.

```
sqlplus username/password@orcl @your_script.sql
```